# Vertx HttpClient does not timeout

Tags: httpclient, vert.x

I am posting not the whole code but code snippets which I think matter to my issue.
I have setup HttpClientOptions as follows.

```
HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions()
                .setDefaultHost(host)
                .setDefaultPort(port)
                .setMaxPoolSize(config.getMaxPoolSize())
                .setConnectTimeout(config.getTimeout());
HttpClient httpClient = vertx.createHttpClient(clientOptions);
```

And then I use this client for a post request as follows:

```
httpClient.post(ePoint, httpClientResponse -> {
            httpClientResponse.bodyHandler(body -> {
                    if (body.length() == 0) {
                        ctx.fail();
                        return;
                    }
                    String bodyString = body.toString();
                    int statusCode = httpClientResponse.statusCode();
                    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                        ctx.fail();
                        return;
                    }
                    logger.info(ctx, "blah blah");


                        ctx.next();

                })
                .exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
                    ctx.fail();
                });
```

But If I do a simulate a timeout at the recipient side exception handler is not called. But I set the time out as follows in the post request exception handler gets called for a time out Exception.

```
httpClient.post(ePoint, httpClientResponse -> {
        httpClientResponse.bodyHandler(body -> {
                if (body.length() == 0) {
                    ctx.fail();
                    return;
                }
                String bodyString = body.toString();
                int statusCode = httpClientResponse.statusCode();
                if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_CREATED) {
                    ctx.fail();
                    return;
                }
                logger.info(ctx, "blah blah");


                    ctx.next();

            }).setTimeout(config.getTimeout())
            .exceptionHandler(throwable -> {
                ctx.fail();
            });
```

Is this a Vertx bug or by design.

Comment: I believe [difference-between-web-service-connection-timeout-and-request-timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34354525/difference-between-web-service-connection-timeout-and-request-timeout) explains the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Following approach will work. We need to setup the timeout at request level

```
HttpClientOptions clientOptions = new HttpClientOptions()
            .setDefaultHost(host)
            .setDefaultPort(port)
            .setMaxPoolSize(config.getMaxPoolSize())
            .setConnectTimeout(config.getTimeout());

HttpClient httpClient = vertx.createHttpClient(clientOptions);


HttpClientRequest request = httpClient.request(HttpMethod.GET, url, response -> {

    //process response

}).exceptionHandler(e -> {
    e.printStackTrace();
    comp.completeExceptionally(e);
});

request.putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
    .setTimeout(timeout).end();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes It seems to be the workaround.